# How can password2 be null in django rest auth registration

Tags: django, django-rest-auth

I don't want to write password2 in the rest auth. So I want to use RegisterSerializer to remove the value of password2, what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just submit password2=password1 on the backend? (i.e. the user will enter password1 then have your app set password2=password1)

Answer (score 0):

You can define your custom serializers for each endpoint without overriding urls and views by adding REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS dictionary in your django settings.

https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html